# dnsmasq - resolve all domains, including path, to the same address

Tags: linux, dns, network-programming, raspberry-pi, dnsmasq

I'm trying to setup a captive portal with a dnsmasq to resolve all domains to an internal IP address.

My /etc/dnsmasq.conf:

```
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=10.0.0.2,10.0.0.10,255.255.255.0,12h
address=/#/10.0.0.1
```

Resolves to IP 10.0.0.1 if the domain includes no path, meaning:

```
http://www.nu.nl/  ->  10.0.0.1
```

but if it includes a path, it will try to go to 10.0.0.1/path

```
http://www.nu.nl/weekend  ->  10.0.0.1/weekend
```

which is not the intended behavior.

I'd like **all** domains to resolve to 10.0.0.1.

Any tips on how to do it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

[DNS is a pretty simple protocol](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt).  Just implement your own server that responds to all requests with the address you want.  It'll be simpler and more reliable than trying to configure some arbitrary tool.  If you want only some devices to be tied to it, use iptables to forward only requests from those address to your server.

A colleague of mine did something similar: [All requests show photos of cats](http://meowni.ca/posts/go-cat-dns-go/).

Comment: thanks. I will be implementing the redirects in Lightpd server. Believe that might be simpler and more effective.

Comment: DNS is not involved in the path.  Your browser resolves only the domain and gets the IP, then connects to that server and requests the path.  You can't ask DNS masq to redirect your web traffic since its a DNS server not an HTTP server

Comment: DNS resolves the name to an IP therefore, as long as your web browser is talking to a DNS server you control, you can cause the browser to always connect to your server which can then do whatever it wants. It's not a _redirect_; it's just a _direct_.  This, by the way, is how some man-in-the-middle attacks are done and why signed certificates are so important with regard to security.